# Time-enabled capabilty and attribute table lost when published as Tiled Mapping Service

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service

I initially published a feature class with a massive number of polygons with large vertices on ArcGIS Online as Feature Service. This feature class has been enabled Time-aware capability. When opened and viewed in Map Viewer, it drew unacceptably slowly but good thing is time was retained.

I was directed by some one on the SE-GIS to publish the feature class to Tiled Mapping Service instead of Feature Service. I did that; the features were drawn pretty fast but Time was lost and no attribute table was available. Is this a bug or time/attribute table just not supported by Tiled Mapping Services?

Answer (score 0):

Time is not supported on tiled map services because it is cached raster images with no time information. Can you generalize the polygon or reduce the vertex count to improve the performance.